# Print console object inside DIV using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console.log

Since i am playing with object to manipulate my HTML5 application. Every time i have to make console log to debug my object. I have taught of print object inside **div** as same like below screenshot

[image]

```
(function () {
    if (!console) {
        console = {};
    }
    var old = console.log;
    var logger = document.getElementById('log');
    console.log = function (message) {
        if (typeof message == 'object') {
            logger.innerHTML += (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(message) : String(message)) + '<br />';
        } else {
            logger.innerHTML += message + '<br />';
        }
    }
})();
```

this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mGDet/) print stringify json in DOM, Instead Is it possible to print object like open/close effect?

Comment: If you mean "is there a trivial way" to have that effect, I don't think there is. Maybe there is a library somewhere that has a plugin for this? I'd love to know this as well.

Comment: Write a recursive tree travelling function and create elements in DIV using js, with js hide show effects for each node name element. Its doable.

Comment: [prettyPrint](https://github.com/padolsey-archive/prettyprint.js) from James Padolsey; [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83wew65w/)